# MacRuby: How to read a plist file?

Tags: plist, macruby

I bet this is super simple and easy but can't find a basic example online. How can I read data from a plist file in my project using MacRuby?

#### Solution:

Turns out there's a few different ways to do it, but the cleanest I've found (so far) is to use the MacRuby helper method `load_plist` (which turns a plist file's contents into a hash). Also, if you're using XCode, you will need to get the file path relative to your app bundle:

```
# there's an AppConfig.plist file in my app bundle

config_path = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('AppConfig', ofType: 'plist')
@config = load_plist File.read(config_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [slide deck about MacRuby](http://www.slideshare.net/phuesler/fun-with-ruby-and-cocoa/77) has some example code for accessing plist files (slides 77-80), the gist of which is that you open the file with `NSDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` and then manipulate it as you would a Ruby Hash, then write it again with `writeToFile_atomically`. The NSDictionary documentation might be useful to you; you can [find it here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).